# valgrind: Heap block lo/hi size mismatch when trying to debug a C++ program running inside Docker container

Tags: c++, docker, valgrind

When trying to debug my C++ binary, I am running into the following issue.

```
valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:307 (get_bszB_as_is): Assertion 'bszB_lo == bszB_hi' failed.
valgrind: Heap block lo/hi size mismatch: lo = 1, hi = 4294967295.
This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.


host stacktrace:
==1747==    at 0x58013284: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/massif-amd64-linux)
==1747==    by 0x58013397: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/massif-amd64-linux)
==1747==    by 0x58013531: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/massif-amd64-linux)
==1747==    by 0x5801BD6D: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/massif-amd64-linux)
==1747==    by 0x5800CDC1: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/massif-amd64-linux)
==1747==    by 0x580614A7: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/massif-amd64-linux)
==1747==    by 0x580737A7: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/massif-amd64-linux)
==1747==    by 0x580738DC: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/massif-amd64-linux)
==1747==    by 0x580C9561: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/massif-amd64-linux)
==1747==    by 0x580C96AA: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/massif-amd64-linux)
==1747==    by 0x580720CD: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/massif-amd64-linux)
==1747==    by 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEE: ???
==1747==    by 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEE: ???
==1747==    by 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEE: ???

sched status:
  running_tid=47

Thread 47: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 1861)
==1747==    at 0x4C2922D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:540)
==1747==    by 0x9A7CB7B: __libc_freeres (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==1747==    by 0x4A24739: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:77)
client stack range: ??????? client SP: 0x289569C8
valgrind stack range: [0x1009516000 0x1009615FFF] top usage: 5064 of 1048576
```

But the interesting fact is, it works wonderfully well when same binary is running outside the container (on a VM). If my source binary has a memory link (as per Valgrind FAQs) I am puzzled as to why I am not encountering the issue when not running in a container.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You probably have some undefined behaviors out there (buffer overflow? maybe), therefore the program displays different behaviors on different platforms... Anyway it is just a guess without actual code provided.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is this issue: https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/issues/74#issuecomment-301464576

I encountered this in a Docker container based off `centos:7` and could also reproduce it using `--tool=memcheck`. Adding `--run-libc-freeres=no` to the valgrind call fixed the issue for me.